# C++ Console : Parsing METAR data

Tags: c++, console, dev-c++

I am working on my first web app (weather visualization) that requires some light c++ on the back end. I am using wget to download the raw text, and c++ console to parse the data and it then writes HTML. This works great so far.

METAR is basically raw weather data from a station. (Time, Date, Conditions, Temp etc). The one I am using currently is :

```
2018/08/10 08:09
KBAZ 100809Z AUTO 00000KT 10SM BKN012 26/23 A3002 RMK AO2 T02610233
```

I have been able to store each set of data into different variables. The set I am looking at with the issue is the "26/23" above, which is the temperature and dew point in Celsius.

So far I have a string called tempAndDewpoint with "26/23" stored in it... I am using substr(0,2) to return the just temperature in a new string called temperature. (since the first number is temperature). This works great.

My question is, what happens if the temperature is below 10, like 9? I could no longer use substring(0,2) because that would then return "9/" as the current temperature.

I hope to find some guidance with this that is not too complicated for me to duplicate. I wasn't even sure what to name this question as I am not sure what this issue is called. Surely it must be common?

Comment: Try to split the string to substrings based on the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware: Negative temperatures in METAR are prefixed with M. So these are valid temp groups: 5/M2  or M8/M12 (negative dew points are in fact icing points). So I would not use a custom parser here:

```
struct TTD {
    short int t;
    short int td;

    bool parse(const char *tempAndDewpoint) {
        const char *next;
        t = parse_partial(tempAndDewpoint, &next);
        if (*next != '/') return false;
        td = parse_partial(next + 1, &next);
        return (*next == '\0');
    }

private:
    static short int parse_partial(const char *beg, const char **next) {
        bool neg = false;
        short int val = 0;
        if (*beg == 'M') {
            neg = true;
            beg += 1;
        }
        while (*beg >= '0' && *beg <= '9') {
            val = val * 10 + (*beg -  '0');
            beg += 1;
        }
        *next = beg;
        if (neg) val = -val;
        return val;
    }

};
```

Comment: Does the METAR format ever change? For example, "26/23" is the 9th piece of data that flows into my program. It's easy for now to input, but are there occasions where the temp/dewpoint is not the 9th block of data? If so, how would I know which one it will be? I am new with METAR

Comment: @David: METAR, SPECI and TAF were meant to be directly human readable, more than parser friendly. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR) gives some elements an a link to a more detailed [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20090905114733/http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/ATpubs/AIM/Chap7/aim0701.html) containing code descriptions. Long time I haven't decoded a METAR myself, but I remember that the number of visibility and significant weather fields may vary, so you can not expect the temp group to be always in 9th position...

Comment: @David ... I once wrote a decoder for METAR, but used lex+yacc to parse it because of the non trivial syntax.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Because this is an ambitious project and I am a beginner programmer, I ended up using a weather.gov webpage and parsing the HTML instead, since it is just as reliable as the METAR. I will return to this page here months down the road because I am going to want to parse the raw METAR instead eventually. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to not store as a string at all. Split the string into two independent numbers. As stated in the other answer you do need to take care of "M" being a prefix for negative numbers but there is no read to parse the numbers by hand:

```
int parseNum(const std::string& str)
{
    size_t pos;
    int num;
    if (!str.empty() && str.front() == 'M')
    {
        num = -std::stoi(str.substr(1), &pos);
        if (pos != str.size() - 1)
        {
          throw std::invalid_argument("invalid input");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        num = std::stoi(str, &pos);
        if (pos != str.size())
        {
          throw std::invalid_argument("invalid input");
        }
    }
    return num;
}

size_t slash = tempAndDewpoint.find("/");
if (slash == std::string::npos)
{
  throw std::invalid_argument("invalid input");
}
int temp = parseNum(tempAndDewpoint.substr(0, slash));
int dew = parseNum(tempAndDewpoint.substr(slash + 1));
```